# dynamic_rnn: inconsistent performance between TF v. 1.0.0 and 1.2.0

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to understand what I have wrong with my `GRUCell` and `dynamic_rnn`, given a drastic decrease in performance after upgrading from TF version 1.0.0 to 1.2.0

Old environment was Ubuntu, Python version 2.7, TF version 1.0.0 and new environment is Ubuntu, Python version 3.5.3, TF version 1.2.0

I saw in the release notes for version 1.2 that there are some changes to how multi-layer RNN is implemented, with some implications to how it was done in versions prior to 1.1, so I thought I'd give it a try.

The relevant part of the old code used to look like this:

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(CELL_SIZE)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
multicell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell]*N_LAYERS, state_is_tuple=False)

output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multicell, X, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=in_state)

preds = tf.contrib.layers.linear(output, 1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(preds - Y_))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LR).minimize(loss)
preds = tf.reshape(preds, [batchsize, -1], name='preds')
```

I see in the [Release Notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/RELEASE.md) :

> Blockquote
>   RNNCell objects now subclass tf.layers.Layer. The strictness described in the TensorFlow 1.1 release is gone: The first time an RNNCell is used, it caches its scope. All future uses of the RNNCell will reuse variables from that same scope. This is a breaking change from the behavior of RNNCells in TensorFlow versions <= 1.0.1. TensorFlow 1.1 had checks in place to ensure old code works correctly with the new semantics; this version allows more flexible uses of RNNCell but can lead to subtle errors if using code meant for TensorFlow <= 1.0.1. For example, writing: MultiRNNCell([lstm] * 5) will now build a 5-layer LSTM stack where each layer shares the same parameters. To get 5 layers each with their own parameters, write: MultiRNNCell([LSTMCell(...) for _ in range(5)]). If at all unsure, first test your code with TF 1.1; ensure it raises no errors, and then upgrade to TF 1.2.

So, I tried both using the old code as outlined above and also an upgraded version, along the lines of these instructions, which looks like this:

```
cells = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(INTERNALSIZE) for _ in range(NLAYERS)]
dropcells = [tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell,input_keep_prob=keep_prob) for cell in cells]
multicell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(dropcells, state_is_tuple=False)
multicell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(multicell, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multicell, X, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=in_state)

preds = tf.contrib.layers.linear(Yr, 1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(preds - Y_))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LR).minimize(loss)
preds = tf.reshape(preds, [batchsize, -1], name='preds')
```

However, both the older and the newer versions of the code produce far worse result during validation and prediction than the old code under version 1.0.0. What's interesting is that I was achieving the best result with only 1-layer anyway, so even if the weight-sharing/non-sharing wasn't done properly, I suppose it shouldn't matter that much with just one layer?

I am trying to understand whether I was achieving the old (good) results by accident and something wasn't working right anyhow, or I need to change something else in order to achieve the same old results under version 1.2 and hopefully even improve those results by being able to not share weights across multiple layers?